# Delphi Tokio IDE - any way to customize?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am moving from Delphi XE4 to 10.2. The new Units Names style of black text against a dark gray background does not suit my eyesight. Can anybody suggest how to change it, preferably without using 3rd party add-ins?

This is how the new style looks like, its very hard for me to read active unit name:
[image: Tokio units tabsheet]

This is how my XE4 unit sheet looks like, and what I expect from the new IDE aswell:
[image]

Comment: This might be a reasonable question if you focused on the colour customisation issue rather than making this just a rant, but as far as I can make out your only complaint is that the active tab highlight has gone from white to dark grey, due perhaps to some sort of Material Design reworking.

Comment: Man sorry for my bad english, I focused on the issue that i just CANT SEE active unit name

Comment: Please rewrite your question to be more answerable on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Sargis Maybe you should adjust your screen settings? Black text on gray background is not optimal for reading, but it is definitely readable - at least on my screen!

Comment: I think you have a valid point about the Units name tab, but a lot of your q is more of a rant about things which are a matter of opinion.  If I were you, I would rewrite your q to say "The new Units Names style of black text against a dark gray background does not suit my eyesight.  Can anybody suggest how to change it, preferably without using 3rd party add-ins?"

Comment: @splash: "at least on my screen" and, more importantly, at least for your eyesight.  Different people have different perceptions of color contrasts, amongst many other things.

Comment: @MartynA Thanks for suggestion, I did as u said

Comment: I've voted to re-open your q.  Hopefully a few others will do, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to exclude ModernTheme250.bpl from the IDE's "Known IDE Package" registry setting:
Open "regedit.exe", navigate to
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\19.0\Known IDE Packages
find the entry named "$(BDS)\Bin\ModernTheme250.bpl". Edit this entry to change the value(!) [not the name] to start with an underscore _. This will disable this package from beeing loaded and you will get back the old style.